# JQuery Price Format for no value/null to number 0

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input

I'm using Jquery price format for a text field. Then when the text field default show "0". I don't want to see 0 number, I want no value is no value. How can I do this ? Please help me. Thank you.

Here is Jquery Price Format : http://jquerypriceformat.com/

Comment: which JQuery Price Format plugin? [this one](http://jquerypriceformat.com/)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use like:

```
$('#example5').priceFormat({
  .....
  clearOnEmpty: true  //set this line will be ok
});
```

and **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/288hfdsw/5/)**